# Laravel Queue Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, notifications, queue

I have 2 environments, QA (1 webserver) and Prod (2 webservers behind a load balancer) that have been set up the same way using a database queue.

On QA everything works just fine.

On Production, I have some strange behaviour...Mailable works fine using the Queue but an email Notification doesn't work with the queue.

If I remove the queue from the notification, the email gets sent.

On QA, I can see both jobs being created in the jobs table.
On Prod, only Mailable gets created in the jobs table.

Example with Activation Email:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SendActivationEmail extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $token;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * SendActivationEmail constructor.
     * @param $token
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->onQueue('social');
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Activation email')
            ->greeting('xxxxxx - Hello!')
            ->line('You need to activate your email before you can start using all of our services.')
            ->action('Activate Email', route('authenticated.activate', ['token' => $this->token]))
            ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

My .env file:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

The file config/queue.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Queue Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The Laravel queue API supports a variety of back-ends via an unified
    | API, giving you convenient access to each back-end using the same
    | syntax for each one. Here you may set the default queue driver.
    |
    | Supported: "null", "sync", "database", "beanstalkd",
    |            "sqs", "iron", "redis"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the connection information for each server that
    | is used by your application. A default configuration has been added
    | for each back-end shipped with Laravel. You are free to add more.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
```

And my Mailable that works with queue:

```
Mail::to($user->email)
                        ->queue(new Welcome($user));
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: What laravel version are you using?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something to do with the .env files

Just make sure that both env files uses the correct Queue Driver.

And that your queue worker is enabled (Cron, supervisorcrl ..)

Answer (score 0):

```
You just need to change this:

public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->onQueue('social');
    }
    

to this:

public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->connection = 'social';
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit what the code snippet is doing?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).